# Case function assistance needed

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have four tables.  I'll call them A-D.

```
SELECT A.ID, B.FirstName, B.LastName, C.Desc, A.Qty, A.Price, D.State,
A.Qty * A.Price AS "Total Price",
CASE D.State
when 'CA' then '***'
when 'MD' then '***'
when 'IL' then '***'
Else D.State
END
FROM A, B, C, D;
```

The above SELECT statement displays all of that data and when the state is CA, MD, or IL it lists a new column called CASE and shows the three asterisks.

I need to get it so that whenever the D.State is CA, MD, or IL that the A.Qty, A.Price, and the Total Price calculation are all filled with the three asterisks as to hide the data and no extra CASE column is created.  If rows don't have CA, MD, or IL in the D.State then the entire row needs to be shown as normal with no asterisks.  I have tried a few loops and I can't seem to get this correct.  If anyone has any thoughts, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to write this as a union.

```
SELECT A.ID, B.FirstName, B.LastName, C.Desc, A.Qty, A.Price, D.State, D.Qty * D.Price AS "Total Price", D.State
FROM A, B, C, D
WHERE D.State NOT IN ('CA', 'MD', 'IL')
UNION ALL
SELECT '****' AS ID, '****' AS FirstName, '****' AS LastName, '****' AS Desc, '****' AS Qty, A.Price, '****' AS State, '****' AS  AS "Total Price", D.State
FROM A, B, C, D
WHERE D.State IN ('CA', 'MD', 'IL')
```

BTW, you are missing the join criteria.

Comment: Thanks and on this I am getting ORA-01790 on line 1: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression.

Comment: Some of the columns are integers (or floats), but in the second query of the union they are strings. You will have to convert/cast the integers to strings (varchar) in the first query.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that issue.  Now the problem I am running into is that the firstname, lastname, description, and state all keep showing the same record over and over.  Only the qty, item price, and total price are changing.  Any thoughts?  I am a beginner here so I am not too familiar with doing joins/unions correctly.

Comment: You need to add the join criteria. I can't help you with that since you haven't shown me your table structure - but basically how that the 4 tables related to each other?

Comment: Table A - id number, qty number, price number, pk = id

Comment: Table B - firstname varchar, lastname varchar, PK = customerid (which i am not using in this select)  Table C -  desc varchar, PK = productid (which i am not using in this select.)      Table D - state char, PK = zip (which I am not using in this select.)  Also, I updated my original code about as price and qty are in table A.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I don't see any columns in common. How are those tables connected?

Comment: A is connected to C through a column called productid.  A is also connected to a table we'll call E through a column called orderid.  E is connected to B through a column called customerid.  B is connected to D through a column called zip.  Sorry I wasn't more clear before.

Comment: In the `WHERE` part of the query (both parts of the `UNION`!) add `A.productID = C.productid AND A.orderid = E.orderid AND .....`, and the same idea for all rest of the tables.

Comment: Yep, that worked and now I get all of the records!  The only issue remaining is that when CA, MD, or IL show up in state, every column is showing the asterisks.  The only three that are supposed to show the asterisks are A.Qty, A.Price, and the Total Price calculation.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured out how to fix that. Let me continue on the rest of the columns, and I'll confirm.

Comment: Yep, everything works perfectly now.  Thanks so much in helping me with this.  Now I understand how the the joins work for multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the case logic on each column:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.FirstName, B.LastName, C.Desc,
case D.State when 'CA' then '***' when 'MD' then '***' when 'IL' then *** else A.Qty end, 
case D.State when 'CA' then '***' when 'MD' then '***' when 'IL' then *** else A.Price end, 
D.State,
case D.State when 'CA' then '***' when 'MD' then '***' when 'IL' then *** else D.Qty * D.Price end AS "Total Price",
CASE D.State
when 'CA' then '***'
when 'MD' then '***'
when 'IL' then '***'
Else D.State
END
FROM A, B, C, D;
```

Comment: Thanks.  On your line 5 I am getting an ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER.

Comment: try doing "else cast(A.Qty as char(10))"